# "Terms and Conditions" in French

Tags: traduction

In German there are "AGB" (Allgemeine Geschäftsbedingungen) which is in English usually "Terms and Conditions". What is it in French? I found in the Internet translations as "conditions générales" and also just "conditions". Is both correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the document is related to the terms and conditions of how something is sold from a party to another one, the most common term in France is:

> **[*Conditions générales de vente*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditions_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rales_de_vente)**.

The [OQLF](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8376555) provides more translations and suggestions depending on what the document precisely contains:

- *conditions*
- *clauses*
- *stipulations*
- *modalités*
- *conditions (générales) (de vente, d'achat, de marché...)*